# Qt: QGridLayout refusing to add widgets

Tags: qt

So i have been trying to use QGridLayout for a while and it keeps giving me the error:
"error: no matching function for call to 'QLayout::addWidget(QScrollArea*, int, int)". I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Here is the part of the code which seems to be causing the error:

```
QScrollArea * setScrollArea(QWidget * w)
{
    w->setStyleSheet("background-color:white;");
    QScrollArea * scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    scrollArea->setWidget(w);
    return scrollArea;
}                                                           ^
.
.
.
shower = new QWidget;
shower->setLayout(new QGridLayout);
shower->layout()->addWidget(setScrollArea(upWindow), 0, 0);
shower->layout()->addWidget(setScrollArea(downWindow), 1, 0);
```

Does anyone have an idea, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QWidget::layout()` returns a simple `QLayout` that has no function `addWidget( QWidget *, int, int )`.
To use the `QGridLayout` functionality, do the following:

```
shower = new QWidget;
QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout;
layout->addWidget(setScrollArea(upWindow), 0, 0);
layout->addWidget(setScrollArea(downWindow), 1, 0);
shower->setLayout(layout);
```